# Finding dependencies on a SPECIFIC COLUMN (modern way, without using sysdepends)

Tags: sql-server

I need to find all views & stored procedures that consume not just a certain table, but a specific column in a table.

The following "seems" to work, but there are numerous warnings to be careful with this method (not reliable for a variety of reasons, soon to be deprecated, etc):

```
SELECT object_name(so.id) TableName, sc.name ColumnName, OBJECT_NAME(sd.id) DependentObjectName,
(SELECT xtype FROM sysobjects so WHERE so.id = sd.id) Object_Type
FROM sysobjects so INNER JOIN syscolumns sc
ON so.id = sc.id
INNER JOIN sysdepends sd
ON so.id = sd.depid and sc.colid = sd.depnumber
WHERE 
    object_name(so.id) = 'MyTableName'
AND sc.name = 'MyColumnName'
order by object_name(so.id), Object_Type
```

Some alternative approaches that are often referenced are sys.sql_dependencies and sys.sql_expression_dependencies, but neither of these have column level granularity.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?  (Or even if you know definitively that it literally cannot be done, it would be helpful to know.)

Comment: [Example 2 of this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/) is for column level searching.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an AdventureWorks example on viewing column dependencies.

```
SELECT ReferencingObject = SCHEMA_NAME(o1.schema_id) + '.' + o1.name,
       ReferencedObject = SCHEMA_NAME(o2.schema_id) + '.'
                          + ed.referenced_entity_name,
       ColumnName = c.name,
       ReferencedObjectType = o2.type,
       ReferencingObjecType = o1.type
FROM   AdventureWorks2012.sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed
       INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2012.sys.objects o1
               ON ed.referencing_id = o1.object_id
       INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2012.sys.objects o2
               ON ed.referenced_id = o2.object_id
       INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2012.sys.sql_dependencies d
               ON ed.referencing_id = d.object_id
                  AND d.referenced_major_id = ed.referenced_id
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c
               ON c.object_id = ed.referenced_id
                  AND d.referenced_minor_id = c.column_id
WHERE  SCHEMA_NAME(o1.schema_id) + '.' + o1.name = 'HumanResources.vEmployee' AND c.name = 'JobTitle'
ORDER  BY ReferencedObject,
          c.column_id;
```

Comment: This looks excellent. Can you comment on whether this AT ALL or POSSIBLY suffers from the same "stale, out of date" issues as sysdepends?  See: https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: ALSO:  Any idea if this would resolve nested dependencies? ie: a PROD depends on a VIEW which depends on TABLE.COLUMN: if we set criteria on TABLE & COLUMN, will both the view *and* the proc show in the results?

Comment: I just don't understand what purpose is served by `where` condition. TS wanted to find dependecies on the specific column. I think the condition should constraint `c.name` and `ed.referenced_id`/`ed.referenced_entity_name`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Here in 2019 - `sys.sql_dependencies` is now in maintenance mode, and the Microsoft team is recommending using only `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`. That being said - it doesn't look like `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` captures the same level of detail.

Comment: @10762409, thanks for that info. I see [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql) may be the way to go, for both details lost in `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, and for being future-proof.